# Magento Controller and Model internal server error

Tags: magento

Below is my js code:

```
$("#personalize_design_button").click(function(){
    category_type = $(".cc-selector input[name='category']:checked").val();
    shape_type = $(".shape-selector input[name='shape']:checked").val();

    $.ajax({
     url: "/index.php/designs/designs/product/ctype/"+category_type+"/stype/"+shape_type,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) 
            {
              alert(data);
            },
        error: function(error)
              {
                 console.log("Error:");
                 console.log(error);

              }
    });

    //$(".col-md-9").append('<div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-3 col-md-3"><div class="productbox"><div class="imgthumb img-responsive"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/business/?ab=1df"></div><div class="caption"><span style="float:left;">Modern Trendy Bedroom</span><span class="pull-right">Rs.129000</span><div class="caption"><span style="float:left;">Tag1</span><span style="float:left;">Tag2</span><span>Tag3</span></div><div class="caption"><span style="float:left;">Tag4</span><span style="float:left;">Tag5</span><span>Tag6</span></div></div></div></div>');
    //$(".col-md-9").load('product_category.phtml');
});
```

My Magento controller class:

```
public function productAction()
{
    $category_type = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ctype');
    $shape_type = $this->getRequest()->getParam('stype');

    ChromePhp::log('ctype-----'.$category_type.'------'.$shape_type);
    //$category_type = $_GET['ctype'];
    //$shape_type = $_GET['stype'];
    $products = Mage::getModel("designs/designs")->getRecentProducts($category_type,$shape_type);
    return json_encode($products);
}
```

and my model class:

```
    <?php

 include 'http://52.25.99.121/ChromePhp.php';
class Homeliv_Designs_Model_Designs extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

    const BEDROOM = 11;

   public function getRecentProducts($category_type,$shape_type)
   {
       ChromePhp::log("inside model-----".$category_type);
       $ctype = 0;
       if($category_type == 1){
           $ctype = BEDROOM;
       }
       //ChromePhp::log("inside model-----".$category_type);
        $products = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($ctype)
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array( 'lt' => 300000 ));
            //->addAttributeToFilter('shapes', array( 'eq' => $shape_type ));
        ChromePhp::log('Total products-----'.count($products);
        foreach ($products as $_product){
            ChromePhp::log('inside model-----'.$_product->getId().'------'.$_product->getShape());
        }
       ChromePhp::log('inside model-------'.count($products));

        return $products;
  }
}
```

This code logs the line in controller but not inside the model. I guess the flow is the ajax request is received by controller which then calls the getRecentProducts() method in model class. But it somehow throws 500 Internal Server error. Need help to fix it.What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Look in the server error logs to see what the problem is

Comment: getting this warning: ERR (3): Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0. shouldn't be an issue, I guess. Also I don't thing model is being called else the first ChromePhp log line should have been called

Comment: seriously....no answer??

Comment: `shouldn't be an issue` but you're doing `include 'http://52.25.99.121/ChromePhp.php';`,  which won't work without the http wrapper, no?

Comment: how to fix it then, I have been head scratching since i asked the question

Comment: Change the server configuration and set allow_url_include to 1

Comment: (or, much much better anyway, copy `ChromePhp.php` to your local server and include it locally.)

Comment: ok so now i fixed that, but whenever i iterate $products, it again throws internal server error